# data unpivot list ids of after group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is link to : [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a9b1/1)

**contents of my table**

```
mysql> select * from tb_dts;
+----+------+------+
| Id | key1 | key2 |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |    1 |
|  2 |    1 |    1 |
|  3 |    1 |    1 |
|  4 |    2 |    1 |
|  5 |    2 |    1 |
|  6 |    2 |    1 |
|  7 |    2 |    1 |
|  8 |    1 |    2 |
|  9 |    1 |    2 |
| 10 |    1 |    2 |
| 11 |    1 |    2 |
| 12 |    1 |    2 |
| 13 |    3 |    1 |
| 14 |    3 |    1 |
| 15 |    3 |    1 |
| 16 |    3 |    1 |
| 17 |    2 |    2 |
| 18 |    2 |    2 |
| 19 |    2 |    2 |
| 20 |    2 |    3 |
| 21 |    2 |    3 |
| 22 |    2 |    3 |
| 23 |    3 |    2 |
| 24 |    3 |    2 |
| 25 |    3 |    2 |
| 26 |    3 |    2 |
+----+------+------+
26 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**This is what I tried**

```
mysql> select group_concat(id) from tb_dts group by key1,key2 limit 0,4;
+------------------+
| group_concat(id) |
+------------------+
| 1,2,3            |
| 8,9,10,11,12     |
| 4,5,6,7          |
| 17,18,19         |
+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id from tb_dts group by key1,key2 limit 0,4;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  8 |
|  4 |
| 17 |
+----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**This is what I expect to get as output for `group by key1,key2 limit 0,4;` : I want all id in one column, which falls within a limit group by key1 and key2, I don't know how to get it group_concat can't help me on this**

for first 4 unique combination of `key1,key2` what all `id` falls is my question that is using `group by key1,key2 limit 0,4;`

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 12 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
| 17 |
| 18 |
| 19 |
+----+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Table Structure**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tb_dts`;
CREATE TABLE `tb_dts` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key1` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  `key2` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `main` (`key1`,`key2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

LOCK TABLES `tb_dts` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `tb_dts` VALUES (1,1,1),(2,1,1),(3,1,1),(4,2,1),(5,2,1),(6,2,1),(7,2,1),(8,1,2),(9,1,2),(10,1,2),(11,1,2),(12,1,2),(13,3,1),(14,3,1),(15,3,1),(16,3,1),(17,2,2),(18,2,2),(19,2,2),(20,2,3),(21,2,3),(22,2,3),(23,3,2),(24,3,2),(25,3,2),(26,3,2);
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to solve question.

First you have to create a Table like

```
CREATE TABLE `Tmp` (
  `Id` int(11)
);
```

And then, after you run the code

```
select @TmpStr = group_concat(id) from tb_dts group by key1,key2 limit 0,1;

--@TmpStr  = "1,2,3"
```

Write a funtion to Split @TmpStr by "," and Insert into Tmp separately.

And keep doing same thing for

```
select @TmpStr = group_concat(id) from tb_dts group by key1,key2 limit 1,1;
select @TmpStr = group_concat(id) from tb_dts group by key1,key2 limit 2,1;
select @TmpStr = group_concat(id) from tb_dts group by key1,key2 limit 3,1;
```

it will show the result like you want.

Comment: You misunderstood the question, for first 4 unique combination of key1,key2 what all id falls is my question that is `group by key1,key2 limit 0,4;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Separator as below

```
 select group_concat(id SEPARATOR '\n') from tb_dts group by key1,key2
```

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter then try :

See Output here : [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a9b1/10/0)

```
select id 
from tb_dts  
where (key1,key2) in (
       select key1,key2 
       from (
                select distinct key1,key2 from tb_dts limit 0,4
       ) as sub
);
```